# Reset signal phase when 2 pi is reached

Tags: phase

I am given the distance from the source of radiation of the harmonic oscillation to the point of observation $R$ and signal frequency $f$.

I need to find the phase shift due to this distance.

When calculated using this formula, the signal phase shift exceeds the maximum $2\pi$.
$$\Delta\varphi=\frac{R\cdot 2\pi}{\lambda}$$

How to write the formula correctly so that the phase incursion is reset to zero when the maximum value is reached?

Comment: use the modulo function
$\Delta\phi = \frac{R 2\pi}{\lambda} mod 2 \pi$

Comment: Or $\Delta \phi = \frac{R 2 \pi}{\lambda} \mod 2\pi$.  Because LaTeX recognizes `\mod` and treats it properly when typesetting (`$\Delta \phi = \frac{R 2 \pi}{\lambda} \mod 2\pi$`).

Comment: I have replaced the inline math and image with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  (edit may be pending). Please check that I did so correctly and consider using MathJax in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the modulo function. Some ways to write this would be

$$\Delta \varphi = \mod \left(\frac{ 2 \pi R}{\lambda},2\pi\right)$$

or

$$
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}\Delta \varphi = \frac{ 2 \pi R}{\lambda} -2\pi\floor{ \frac{R}{\lambda}}   
$$

where $\lfloor \rfloor$ is the truncation symbol.

In many cases it's actually preferable NOT to reset the phase as it creates a discontinuity.